# Jquery Datatable data to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I am working on a scenario where, need to pass datatable Data to server side.
Here is what i tried -

To get Datatable data in view -

```
var oTable = $('#DetailTable').dataTable();
var data = oTable.fnGetData();
```

Then trying to post data using ajax cal -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",                   
    dataType: 'text',
    data:  data,
    url: "/Admin/SaveAll",                  
    success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

And in Controller action method -

```
public ActionResult SaveAll(string data)
{ 
}
```

I am getting null value at server side. How to pass all datatable data to server side ?

Comment: Do you have `dom` element(s) in you data table ?

Comment: Why you want to pass all datatable data to server ? I think you scenario is not good.

Comment: Yes, i have one image "delete" in each row.

Comment: In this scenario, user allowed to create a Master record with number of child records. So as user adds child record against Master record, child records are showed in datatable  then on submit click what to take all records to Server side.

Comment: So from what I have understood, why not send child records with theirs parent Id to server instead of all Master and Details records ?

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to send only the child records which are in datatable.

Comment: well, can you retrieve child records of master record?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in this case you are using the old style API ( fnGetData ) with a new style API object. I would suggest you use row().data() instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` parameter in you `SaveAll` method is string in the other side you are getting table record by `fnGetData()` this function will return record(s) in JSON format so you should to make string of `JSON` and then pass it as `Ajax` data,

so try this

```
var postData = JSON.stringify({ 'data': data});

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        data: postData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Admin/SaveAll",                  
        success: function (result) {
        }
    });
```

as you can see [this link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26699/post-datatable-data-to-server-in-json-format-with-column-names) there was discussed how to send datatable data to server by `ajax` and they are using `JSON.Stringify`.

if you get circular refrence error while stringifying datatable data please take a look at [here](https://datatables.net//forums/discussion/comment/61981/#Comment_61981) and [here](https://datatables.net//forums/discussion/comment/74320/#Comment_74320)
there are some good advice and you may find external lib to do this.

I hope this give you a hand to resolve your problem.

Comment: I am getting error "0x800a13aa - JavaScript runtime error: Circular reference in value argument not supported"

Comment: I have tested it and `postData` initiated by data table string data, did you try clearly?

Comment: var postData line throwing same error - 0x800a13aa - JavaScript runtime error: Circular reference in value argument not supported